# An if statement short circuting after the "or" before even checking the "and"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a function that checks if a number can be divisible or not. It checks that if the two numbers return a float that is not equal to that same float in an int form.

For example:

- 4/2 = 2.0 but 2.0 == int(2.0) is True, therefore the float that 4/2 returned is still equal to the int form of that same float.
- 4/3 = 1.33333333333 but 1.33333333333 == int(1.33333333333) is False.

Now here is my function, which takes a string like so "4/2":

```
def is_div(s):
    split_s = s.split("/")
    firs = int(split_s[0])
    seco = int(split_s[1])
    divided = firs/seco
    print(divided)
    print(int(divided))
    if firs > seco or firs == 0 and divided == int(divided):
        return True
    return False
```

Now at first glance to me it looked like it was working for every possible input, then I tried `is_div("42/9")` and for some reason it returned True even though the check after the `and` is not True, then why did it return True after my function was run? Why did it not carry on and also check the `and`? It only checked the `firs > seco` and then decided ok imma head in then.

Comment: Precedence of operators : ```firs > seco or firs == 0 and divided == int(divided)``` is actually ```firs > seco or (firs == 0 and divided == int(divided))```. So if ```firs > seco``` , no need to eval the second part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is put parentheses like this:

```
if (firs > seco or firs == 0) and divided == int(divided):
```

It returned True because it checked the following condition: 
`A or B and C`, which is the same as `A or (B and C)`: `and` has a higher priority over `or`. Since A is True, the output was True.

Answer (score 0):

The binding of `and` is higher than the `or` operator. That means the expression
`firs > seco or firs == 0 and divided == int(divided)` is equal to `firs > seco or (firs == 0 and divided == int(divided))`.

So the expression will be True if `firs > seco`is `True` or `(firs == 0 and divided == int(divided))` is `True`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 0):

Not actually required but…

We may try a different implementation:

```py
import fractions

def is_div(s):
    return fractions.Fraction(*(int(x) for x in s.split('/'))).denominator == 1
```

And we can test it.

```py
assert is_div('0/1') == True
assert is_div('1/1') == True
assert is_div('2/1') == True
assert is_div('0/2') == True
assert is_div('1/2') == False
assert is_div('2/2') == True
assert is_div('3/2') == False
assert is_div('0/3') == True
assert is_div('1/3') == False
assert is_div('2/3') == False
assert is_div('3/3') == True
assert is_div('4/3') == False
```